# HeadFirst JS: questions in an example of code

Tags: javascript

The purpose of the function is to validate input. The input should consist of two characters: the first one A-G; the second one: 0-6; e.g A0; B2. The example is taken from the book. 
I want to understand is there a point in lines such as: "guess===null (Can a string be equal to null?)" ; " column < 0 " row >= model.boardsize;
Note that model.boardsize is a specified number. In this case, it is 7.

```
function parseGuess(guess) {
  var alphabet = ["A" , "B" , "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];


   if (guess===null || guess.length !== 2) {

       alert("Oops, please enter a letter and a number on the board.");
    } else {
      var firstChar = guess.charAt(0);
      var row = alphabet.indexOf(firstChar);
      var column = guess.charAt(1);

      if (isNaN(row) || isNaN(column)) {
        alert("Oops, that isn't on the board.");
      } else if (row < 0 || row >= model.boardSize ||
        column < 0 || column >= model.boardSize) {

        alert("Oops, that's off the board!");

      } else {
        return row + column;
      }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: Yes, a string can be null or even equal to null.

Comment: What do you think about column < 0; row >= model.boardSize? Are these conditions necessary in this code?

Comment: @Adam A string cannot be null. In JS, string and null are distinct data types. A variable cannot be both string and null at the same time. A string can be empty ("") but that is not the same as it being null. Even something like `new String(null)` creates the object string "null".

Comment: @skyline3000 even if one were to do something like var myName = 'null'; ?

Comment: @Adam Correct. that would mean that `myName` is equal to the *string* "null", but that is not the same as it being the data type `null` (which is what this function is checking for). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures on data types and primitive values.

Comment: Then what does the conditional check by guess==null when guess is expected to be a string? the guess variable is inserted by the user.

Comment: @ArthurHmayakyan Just because that's what you're expecting doesn't mean that's what you'll get. Again, JavaScript is a dynamically typed language meaning there's nothing enforcing your function to only accept strings. You never know what happens on the client or what different browsers might do in different conditions, so it's always better to do a type check and ensure you are getting something you can work with, otherwise your program will throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the book and it's not clear how this function gets called, but I would say that's a pretty poor check for determining if `guess` has a good, expected value. The typical reason why one would check for `null` first is because if `guess` is `null`, then `guess.length` will throw a `TypeError` because `null` does not have a `length` property. Since it is the first check in the OR condition, it short-circuits the second half and shows the `alert()` right away when `guess` is `null`.

However, an error would also be thrown if `guess` was `undefined` (a common case when an argument isn't passed in the function call) or a boolean. Additionally, objects, arrays, and other data structures also have a `length` property, which means they could pass the first `if` condition test but then methods like `indexOf` and `charAt` would throw errors. You would probably want to change it to something like:

```
if (typeof guess !== 'string' && guess.length !== 2) {
```

As for the board size, yes you want to check if the column is less than 0 or greater than the size, otherwise you will pick something out-of-bounds and your program will throw an error.

Comment: guess is inserted by the user in:
   <input type="text>

Comment: In that case, it is unlikely anything other than a string will come into the function since an `<input>` element's `value` property is always a `DOMString`, even when it is empty, but you never know what goes on in the client's machine, so it's still considered a best practice to ensure you are working with a string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text

Comment: Just to clarify, you are not actually checking if a string is equal to null. JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, meaning variables can be any data type at any time. You are checking if the argument that got passed to the function is a string.